# ngAnimate on ngShow. Preventing animation when it starts first time

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I was playing around with recently added angular.js animations feature, and this doesn't work as desired

```
<style>
    .myDiv{
        width:400px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:red;
    }
    .fadeIn-setup,.fadeOut-setup {
      -webkit-transition: 1s linear opacity;
      -moz-transition: 1s linear opacity;
      -o-transition: 1s linear opacity;
      transition: 1s linear opacity;
    }
    .fadeIn-setup{
      opacity:0;
    }
    .fadeOut-setup{
      opacity:1;
    }
    .fadeIn-setup.fadeIn-start {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .fadeOut-setup.fadeOut-start{
        opacity:0;
    }
</style>

<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
       <input type='button' value='click' ng-click='clicked()' />  
       <div ng-show="foo == true"  class='myDiv' ng-animate="{show: 'fadeIn', hide:'fadeOut'}">
       </div>
     </div>
</div>

function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.foo = false;
    $scope.clicked = function(){
       $scope.foo = !($scope.foo);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kx4TS/1

it spoils away myDiv on the `dom.ready` and starts it fading out. Whereas it initially should be hidden. How to fix that?

Comment: I figured: for my case it works if you make style of myDiv opacity:0. But it only works if I directly set the style, not through the class.

Comment: I'm thinking this sort of thing should be done in a directive where you can hide the element initially and fade it in when necessary inside of a `$watch` callback.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been fixed now. Upgrade to 1.1.5.

Comment: This still persists in 1.1.5

Comment: I think they fixed it related with page load, see e.g. http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html: "Version 1.1.5 of AngularJS now properly avoids animating elements that are instantiated before bootstrap. So basically the first animation is skipped thus preventing any flickr or premature hiding." -- but it seems to still happen when loading fragments. The solution with `style=display:none` works for me in this case.

Comment: @ac360 you can add a ng-hide class on the element manually to hide it on init

Answer (score 40):

This issue still persists even now with 1.2.22. However, one of these solutions solves it very easily.

After trying all the solutions mentioned here I wanted to specifically highlight cocoggu's  suggestion to ac360 as it is by far the most concise and it "just works".

As he suggests, simply adding the ng-hide class to the offending element resolves the problem immediately. - It prevents the initial animation glitch and allows all subsequent animations to behave as expected.

**Working Solution** thanks to cocoggu

`<div id="offending-element" class="ng-hide"></div>`

Comment: Works well with angular 1.3.10 :)

Answer (score 10):

I have found 2 different solutions for your problem

The easiest solution:
Add a inline style to the div **style="display:none"**

The other solution is to add an initial class to the div with **ng-class="state"**
and reset the class when the button is clicked

```
function ctrl($scope){
    $scope.state = 'hide';
    $scope.foo = false;
    $scope.clicked = function() {
       $scope.state = undefined;  
       $scope.foo = !($scope.foo);
    }
}
```

together with the following css:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

I think I would use the first and most simple solution

Comment: `style="display:none"` worked for me (whereas `class="ng-hide"` did not). Running v1.5.6

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

```
<div ng-class="ng-hide" ng-show="foo == true"  class='myDiv'">
```

this is the important part here: `ng-class="ng-hide"`

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments, the above would not work. It should look like this:

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="foo == true"  class='myDiv'">
```

Comment: @codeepic: what exactly does not work? could you please clarify? thx

Comment: Adding ng-class='ng-hide'. You want the ng-hide class to be applied before the Angular application starts, to prevent the flicker. You are better off setting class="ng-hide" on the element you want to be initially hidden. CSS is parsed before the JS, so in this case ng-hide class is applied before Angular app is initialized and the element is initially hidden without the annoying flicker.